# Who or whom in this case

Tags: grammar

Is it

> Ever wonder whom has the skills

or

> Ever wonder who has the skills?

I believe it is who but unsure.

> Ever wonder whom you could team up with

, or

> who

In the second case I could use him or her in the answer, therefore I think whom is right.

?

Comment: No, it's "who". "whom" is an object, not a subject.

Comment: @Bamar thanks. see updated question please

Comment: I think the socond one should technically be "whom", but most people will say "who".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever wonder who has the skills?  - This the correct.
However
Ever wonder whom you could team up with
This is wrong as written. First, do not end sentences in a preposition.
"Ever wonder with whom you could team."
Whom is almost always the object of a preposition.
To test, try substituting "he" or "him" where "he" equates to "who" and "him" equates to "whom."

Comment: *"First, do not end sentences in a preposition"* - Why not?

Comment: Formal writing never ends a sentence in a preposition. This is considered incorrect grammar.  Unfortunately, too many people are unable to separate informal writing from formal writing. My opinion, is that one should never end a sentence in a preposition.